# Rendering inconsistency between SSRS and browser causing misaligned tables

Tags: reporting-services

I am using SSRS to report numbers and percentages and display them in a matrix using a column grouping (so new "rows" of data populate new columns rather than rows).

In order to make a "nice" header for each row that spans several rows I have created two tablixes, one for the headers and one containing the data. These two tablixes have both been dropped into a list in order to keep them aligned (being contained in a list is also essential if I want to use them within a multi-page report). The heights of each cell have been defined carefully to ensure that the two tables align and appear as one table.

When I view the report in SSRS everything appears more or less as I would expect. However, when I view the same report via IE the rows become misaligned.

[image]

Is there an easy explanation as to why this happens?

My best guess is that the heights I've specified in mm and cm are being converted into another unit and the inconsistency is being introduced via  a rounding error.

i.e. the headers are 15mm height, numbers are 7mm height and percentages are 8mm high. Normally 8+7=15 but perhaps conversion(8)+conversion(7)=/=conversion(15)

If this is the case then it would be useful to know the native or "correct" units to use in SSRS if I want to avoid this kind of conversion error.

Comment: Which browser(s) have you tested against?

Comment: IE version 11 but I believe it is set to render in compatibility to version 5 (this is an organisation standard which I need to stick to).

Comment: The thick border is probably throwing it off by a point each row. But really, why not have these all in the same table and merge the cells? I don't see how putting them in a list would help. One property you can check is to make sure `CanGrow` is off on all the textboxes.

Comment: CanGrow is false for all boxes. The thicker border has no impact on cell sizes (I have verified this in IE). Containing the table in a list makes it possible to create pagebreaks since, for some reason, pagebreaks do not function correctly when applied via column groupings (based on research this is a known bug/quirk).

Comment: Putting the headers and data into the same table is an obvious solution but unfortunately I am not able to merge cells vertically (this may be an artifact of the way I've created the table). Potentially I can recreate the table from scratch to enable vertical merging but I'd like to avoid this if possible. I'd also like to understand why the rendering isn't behaving as I'd expect in case it becomes relevant for some other aspect of the report.